# linq to sql : The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm encountering an error

> The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected

when adding my stored procedure to my `.dbml` model. I'm using SQL Server 2008 so I can't use `concat`.. any other work around?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    b.FirstName + ',' + b.LastName + '-' + a.AgentName as AgentName, 
    a.LocationCode
FROM dbo.person a 
LEFT JOIN dbo.PersonName b ON a.PersonID = b.PersonID 
INNER JOIN dbo.Agt c ON a.LocationCode = c.LocationCode
WHERE 
    a.STATUS = 1
    AND c.AgentName = @AgentName
```

Comment: Side note: I'd recommend using **more meaningful** table aliases rather than just `a`, `b`, `c`. Use `dbo.Person p`, `dbo.PersonName pn`, `dbo.Agt a` and then your table aliases become a lot more expressive and your query becomes a lot clearer and easier to understand!

Comment: hi thanks for the concern, sorry i was in a hurry to recreate my stored procedure here.